# Export a samba share to a non-domain users

Tags: networking, samba, cifs, active-directory

I have samba server configured as domain member. I'd like to export one share to 2 computers in addition to authenticated domain users. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by adding `auth methods = sam winbind` to smb.conf to add local authentications.